# What classification algorithm should one use after seeing that t-SNE separates classes well?

Tags: classification, tsne

Let's assume we have a classification problem and at first we want to get some insight from the data and we do t-SNE. The result of t-SNE separates classes very well. This implies that it is possible to build classification model that will also separate classes very well (if t-SNE doesn't separate well then it doesn't imply much).

Knowing that t-SNE focuses on local structure and that it can separate classes well: What are classification algorithms that should work well on this problem?  Scikit suggests SVM with a Gaussian RBF kernel, but what are the others?

Comment: (+1) K-nearest-neighbours could be one very simple and easy-to-implement natural choice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First a brief answer, and then a longer comment:

**Answer**

SNE techniques compute an N ×N similarity matrix in both the original data space and in the low-dimensional embedding space in such a way that the similarities
form a probability distribution over pairs of objects. Specifically, the probabilities are generally given by a normalized Gaussian kernel computed from the input data or from the embedding. In terms of classification, this immediately brings to mind [instance-based learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance-based_learning) methods. You have listed one of them: SVM's with RBF, and @amoeba has listed kNN. There are also [radial basis function networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_network), which I am not an expert on.

**Comment**

Having said that, I would be doubly careful about making inferences on a dataset just looking at t-SNE plots. t-SNE does not necessarily focus on the local structure. However, you can adjust it to do so by tuning the `perplexity` parameter, which regulates (loosely) how to balance attention between local and global aspects of your data.

In this context, `perplexity` itself is a stab in the dark on how many close neighbours each observation may have and is user-provided. The [original paper](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume9/vandermaaten08a/vandermaaten08a.pdf) states: *“The performance of t-SNE is fairly robust to changes in the perplexity, and typical values are between 5 and 50.”* However, my experience is that getting the most from t-SNE may mean analyzing multiple plots with different perplexities.

In other words, tuning `learning rate` and `perplexity`, it is possible to obtain very different looking 2-d plots for the same number of training steps and using the same data.

This *Distill* paper [How to Use t-SNE Effectively](http://distill.pub/2016/misread-tsne/) gives a great summary of the common pitfalls of t-SNE analysis. The summary points are:

1. Those hyperparameters (e.g. learning rate, perplexity) really matter
2. Cluster sizes in a t-SNE plot mean nothing
3. Distances between clusters might not mean anything
4. Random noise doesn’t always look random.
5. You can see some shapes, sometimes
6. For topology, you may need more than one plot

Specifically from points 2, 3, and 6 above, I would think twice about making inferences about the separability of the data by looking at individual t-SNE plots. There are many cases where you can 'manufacture' plots that show clear clusters using the right parameters.

Comment: Berkmeister: Everything what you wrote make sense. My problem is quite easy to describe: I want to make classification model as good as possible. How can I use it to improve the quality of model? My best guess was that t-SNE can 'suggest' which method might be relevant to given problem.

Comment: Please see edit, instance-based learning methods would be compatible with any clues you may get from t-SNE plots.

Comment: (+1): Thanks for the answer, I was looking exactly for this. I will accept the answer within two days.